# How to reload current page before going to link? ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Here's the view

```
<a href="{{$cart_items->contains('id',$productItem->id) ? route('IndexCart'): route('AddToCart')}}" class="item_add" id="{{$productItem->id}}"><p class="number item_price {{$cart_items->contains('id',$productItem->id) ? 'added': ''}}">
                <i> </i>${{$productItem->price}}
                           </p>
                        </a>
```

So I need to reload current page after 2nd click on it

trying this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(c) {
        $('.item_add').click(function (event) {
        var addButton = $(this).children('p');
    if(addButton.hasClass('added'))
    {
        linktocart.attr('onclick','location.reload(true)');
    }

    else
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var data = {'cart_item_id': id};
        var carturl = "http://site.loc/cart";
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                data: data,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (html) {
                        addButton.addClass('added');
                        addButton.css('background', 'green');
                        addButton.parent('a').attr('href', carturl);
                        $('#addOrAlready').text('Added');
                }
            });
    }
});
```

It doesn't work, I guess, because I prevented default when I clicked it 1st time, so I think I need to "un"prevent default to make reload before going to link work. How can I do it? I need it because i guess chrome loads cached copy of page which hasn't applied changes on server.

Comment: try to proper indent code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle mousedown event instead of click.